# how to assign variable from inside an actionlistener to one outside

Tags: java, variable-assignment

I'm a C programmer who was handed a last minute Java GUI task.  Given that I am not a GUI or Java person, I have created two objects:

1 is a text box, which I'm hoping to be assigned the results of the 2nd object.
2 is a combo box.  When user selects from the combo box, I wish for that value to be populated into my first object (textfield).  Here is my actionListener():

```
class Foo {
    // declared instance variable
    private String theValue;

    // created textField, and JComboBox thingies

    listBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
           // this line produces the reported error
           //textField.setText( (String)(((JComboBox)e.getSource()).getSelectedItem()) ); 

         // this line works, but then get below error when try to assign theValue outside method
           theValue = ((JComboBox)e.getSource()).getSelectedItem();
        }                    
    });
...
textField.setValue(theValue);   // errors out
```

and get the following (apparently well know Java error): Cannot refer to a non-final variable 
textfield inside an inner class defined in a different method

The commented line produced the same results.  I was hoping to be able to assign theValue as the value of my text field, but can not obviously declare I within the listener, as then there is the scope problem.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: For clarification:  the assignment to theValue within the actionPerformed() method does not produce an error.  But when I later try to assign theValue to another variable outside the listener, I got the reported error.

Comment: Thank you MadProgrammer!  problem solved...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either make the `JTextField` `final` or make it an instance field within the class.

```
final JTextField textField = ...
```

or

```
public class ... {

    private JTextField textField;

    public ...() { = new JTextField(...);
```

You can do this for you other variables to.  Typically, unless you have some reason to do otherwise, I would suggest using instance fields.  Take a look at [Understanding Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) for some more details...

You can think of instance fields like "private" variables in C, those declared within the C file itself, where the can not be referenced externally to the file they are declared in (sorry VERY long time since I've done C so that might not be entirely correct)

**Updated**

Firstly, GUI's tend to be event driven, that is, they don't operate in a linear/procedural fashion.  You set up a bunch of callbacks and wait for something to trigger them.  When the callback is triggered, you take appropriate action...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField textField;
        private JComboBox comboBox;
        private String theValue;

        public TestPane() {
            textField = new JTextField(10);
            comboBox = new JComboBox(new String[]{"Banana", "Apple", "Grapes", "Strawberries"});
            comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    theValue = (String)comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                    textField.setText(theValue);
                }
            });
            comboBox.setSelectedItem(null);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            add(textField, gbc);
            add(comboBox, gbc);
        }

    }

}
```

In the example, the `ActionListener` assigned to the `JComboBox` is not called immediately, meaning that the remaining code below the assignment will run immediately and before the `ActionListener` has any chance of been called.

Think of it like a function pointer or callback.  You can pass it to another function, but you don't know when it might be called...

When the state of the `JComboBox` changes and triggers and action event, the `ActionListener`s `actionPeformed` method is called, at which time you can obtain the current value and apply it to the text field and assign it to your variable...or what ever else you need to do...

Notice, I attached the `ActionListener` and the called `comboBox.setSelectedItem(null)`, this will actually cause the `ActionListener` to be notified...tricky ;)

Comment: I'm unclear as to how to make use of the final variable.  Currently I have theValue declared as private in the class, outside of the listener.  I can not declare it as final, since I don't have a value to assign it (which final will require).   I believe I've tried the other solution you've mentioned, about creating the JTextField, which again is declared (non-final) outside the listener, which caused the reported error.  Guess I need further details :-)

Comment: Code doesn't fit in comments, better to update the question ;)

Comment: Have you tried making it into a instance field like the second example?  Make sure you don't redcalre it witih the method

Comment: I changed the code as shown, but this is what caused my error in the beginning.  Does this match what you've described ?  Thanks again!

Comment: @frododot I added a runnable example, hope it helps

Comment: Best explanation I've seen online!  Will give this a whirl, and will post results.  Thank you!

Comment: Problem solved.  Thank you for your concise and easy-to-understand explanation.  You've eased my whirlwind tour into Java :-)